# Raspberry PI remote debug GTK error

Tags: linux, opencv, netbeans, gtk, raspberry-pi

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 on my Win7 machine to develop Raspberry Pi opencv C++ application.
I'm building & debugging the application remotely on the Raspberry Pi from my Win7 machine.

At run time the application fails with **"Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"** error when reaches the line:

```
imshow("source", src);
```

When I'm running the exact same application from the Raspberry Pi and not remotely via SSH everything works as expected.

Is there any way that I can configure NetBeans to open GTK windows at the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add **DISPLAY=:0** Environment variable.

At **File** menu select **Project Properties (yourprojectname)** to open Project Properties window.
At **Categories:** click **Run** and then click **Environment**, add variable name **DISPLAY** with value **:0**

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried this with the Rasberry Pi, but assuming it is like other linux systems perhaps this will get you started.

To have the Gtk program display on your windows system will need a version of X Windows ( the  linux/unix graphics server) for Windows the operating system. You can get it as one of the packages in Cygwin. (http://x.cygwin.com/) Get cygwin https://cygwin.com/index.html during setup select the xinit package. You also either need to enable port-forwarding in ssh or set the DISPLAY variable on the Rasberry Pi to your windows host:0.

To have the Gtk program display on the Rasberry Pi when started from Windows you just need to allow remote hosts to open windows.

Try the command :

xhost +

in the Rasberry Pi shell before trying to have the program started from windows.

Another option would be to start the program on the Rasberry Pi with gdbserver and then attach to the already running program with Netbeans.
You will need to install the gdbserver plugin for Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to getting the X window manager working on Windows would be to get a remote desktop running on both machines. VNC is a popular client and server for this. This would allow you to run the window for Netbeans and use the system as if it were your desktop from another location.

There is even a download specifically for Raspberry pi here:

https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/latest/